# What is wrong with my onResume method?

Tags: android, listview, android-intent

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    show = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String Title = intent.getExtras().getString("name");
    addArray.add(Title);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, addArray);
    show.setAdapter(adapter); 
}
```

My app keeps crashing because something is wrong with my `onResume()` method. Am I not allowed to use `getIntent()` when trying to create a `ListView` using the `ArrayAdapter`?

Comment: What is the stacktrace?

Comment: Please post the error you get when the app crashes

Comment: Passing of data between two activities can be done using the Bundle which is the argument of oncreate() method so if u want to get the data from other activity u should call it in oncreate() and initialize list view in oncreate too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are launching a new activity with setting bundle then getIntent().getExtra() will work properly as expected.

Your getIntent().getExtra() method is returning null value that is why you are not able to initialize the array adapter. Put a check for not null.

Either you can use:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    String Title = intent.getExtras().getString("name");
    addArray.add(Title);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, addArray);
    show.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a fragment, place the `findViewById` method inside `onCreateView()`, set the adapter inside `runOnUIThread()` (if your code has network calls) and accept the intent inside `onCreate()`. If you are using an activity, you might want to do these inside `onCreate()`. Plus, use method to notify adapter about possible data changes.